# Netlogo: How can I specify the turtle of the smallest ID and the turtle of the second smallest ID both?

Tags: netlogo

How can I specify the turtle of the smallest ID and the turtle of the second smallest ID both? The following is a sample program, but it does not work well. Especially "ask min - one - of turtles [who + 1]" I think this syntax is maybe wrong, but I do not understand well. Is there any other way to this? I probably need your advice. Thank you.

```
globals [ nb-white nb-red ]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
end

to go

  ask patch 0 0 [sprout 1]
  ask min-one-of turtles [who] [set color white]   
  ask min-one-of turtles [who + 1] [set color red]

  ask (turtles-on patch 0 0) [
    set nb-white count turtles-here with [color = white]
    set nb-red count turtles-here with [color = red]
  ]

end
```

Comment: Luke's answer is correct, but he's especially right to point out that you should not be using `who` numbers. If you ever find yourself tempted to use `who` for anything, come ask another question here. Someone will most likely be able to suggest a better way to do things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `[who + 1]` as a reporter will get each turtle to report its `who` number plus one- so the turtle with `who` of 0 will report 1, turtle with `who` of 1 will report 2, and so on- so the `min-one-of` turtle will not change.

If you *must* use `who` numbers, which is not recommended, you could try:

```
globals [ nb-white nb-red ]

to setup
  clear-all

  crt 2
  ask first sort turtles [ set color white ] 
  ask item 1 sort turtles [ set color red ]

  set nb-white count turtles with [color = white]
  set nb-red count turtles with [color = red]

  reset-ticks
end
```

`sort turtles` returns an ascending ordered list of agents- `first` will return the turtle with the lowest `who` (the same as `min-one-of turtles [who]`), `item 1` the second lowest.

**Edit:**

```
globals [ nb-white nb-red ]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask patch 0 0 [sprout 1]
  ask first sort turtles [ set color white ] 
  if count turtles > 1 [
    ask item 1 sort turtles [ set color red ]
  ]

  set nb-white count turtles with [color = white]
  set nb-red count turtles with [color = red]
end
```

To reiterate (and as Nicolas stated) you should definitely consider if you truly need to use `who` numbers for this- it is usually not needed, it's not very good practice, and can cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a wonderful syntax. And I wrote on my actual model and tested it. However, there was a problem specification in the "item" syntax, and the following running error message appeared at the same time. "Since the length of list [(turtle 0)] is only 1, there is no first element." Perhaps this problem is because my model uses "sprout 1" and I am running forever As it is in the sample code when asking it). What should I do in this case? Thank you.

Comment: @goodgest - you're right, it's because you start out with only one turtle on the first call of `go`. How you handle that will probably depend on what you actually want to happen, but probably the simplest way would be to wrap the `item` line in an `if` statement so that it is only called when there is more than one turtle. See edits for a quick example